# Telerik RadGrid always display X rows, even if there are only Y data rows on the last page where Y < X

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, telerik, radgrid

I have a telerik rad grid with PageSize=10. The problem is if I have 34 items. On the last page, there will only be 4 rows. Is there a mode to force to control to render with 6 empty null rows or do I have to implement this myself by adding blank rows o my DataSource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of telerik forum posts that talk about adding rows to a RadGrid.

[Adding blank row to rad grid](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/adding-blank-row-to-rad-grid.aspx)

[Showing empty cells](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/showiing-empty-cells.aspx)

Hope this helps some.